# JTextArea won't update java

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextarea

I'm trying to update a JTextArea using the .append. I'm sending in a string to the method from another class and I know the textBox method gets the string as I can use .println to test it. The only thing is it does not update the JTextArea which is strange as when I first start the program and the gui is being created i'm able to update it.

```
public void textBox (String text){

    textArea.append(text);

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the reference textArea points to the JTextArea where you are looking at?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  The problem is unlikely to be in the snippet posted.  And 'textBox' is a poor method name for updating a text area - maybe 'appendOutput'?

Answer (score 0):

Try using textArea.append(text + "\n");
I too had the same problem . I solved it by adding a "\n" at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(text);
      textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        String appendText = "jumps over the lazy dog.";
       textArea.append(appendText);
```